# Change the color gradually

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-fragments, android-animation

I made **sliding up panel** with the help of this library. Click [here](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) Now I am trying to change color of top sliding panel gradually when user will open panel or close. Next code below that I used change the color in flash. **How to change color gradually?**

```
@Override
public void onPanelLayout(View panel, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState state) {
       LinearLayout titleBar = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.dragView);
       if(state == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED){
                   titleBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#03A9F4"));
 }
 else if (state == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED || state == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED){
                    titleBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff9431"));
 }
 }
```

Thanks for any help and idea!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html)

Your code would look something like this:

```
ColorDrawable transparentDrawable = new ColorDrawable();
transparentDrawable.setColor(0x00000000); //transparent white

ColorDrawable finalColorDrawable = 
finalColorDrawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff9431")); //your colour

Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[]{transparentDrawable, finalColorDrawable};
TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable = new TransitionDrawable(layers);

titleBar.setBackground(transitionDrawable);
transitionDrawable.startTransition(1000); //duration in milliseconds
```